# MySQL SELECT then immediately UPDATE and return only selection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

`'SELECT prod_id FROM prod_keys WHERE key_value = ? AND key_used IS NULL; UPDATE prod_keys SET key_used = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() WHERE key_value = ?;'`

I need to verify the key is valid (exists and not used), mark it as used (with current timestamp) and have it returned its product id (product it belongs to).

Doing this in PHP with PDO and newbie to MySQL.

**Although this somehow works, I need to:**

1. be sure that these two operations happen at once (and not separated),
2. simplify this that key_value needs to be passed only once,
3. at best returns back only prod_id

**Table with random, sample keys:**

```
CREATE TABLE `prod_keys` (
  `key_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key_value` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `prod_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key_used` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `key_created` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

```
INSERT INTO `prod_keys` (`key_id`, `key_value`, `prod_id`, `key_used`, `key_created`) VALUES
(1, 'ABCDE-ABCDE', 3, '2021-02-08 11:29:34', '2021-02-06 11:27:55'),
(2, 'YXCVB-YXCVB', 4, NULL, '2021-02-06 11:27:55'),
(3, 'NCZVG-XEQJH', 7, NULL, '2021-02-08 11:27:55'),
(4, 'S1JS0-UYYGA', 3, NULL, '2021-02-08 11:27:55'),
(5, '4DHQ9-CHY4L', 5, NULL, '2021-02-08 11:27:55'),
(6, '0DDQG-ZOP3A', 7, NULL, '2021-02-08 11:27:55'),
(7, '1TPSK-XBDYW', 3, NULL, '2021-02-08 11:27:55'),
(8, 'M2UEB-7O15L', 4, NULL, '2021-02-08 11:27:55'),
(9, 'VWAV2-3728O', 6, NULL, '2021-02-08 11:27:55'),
(10, '6215O-O94Y5', 5, NULL, '2021-02-08 11:27:55'),
(11, 'R22QT-9PQ0O', 4, NULL, '2021-02-08 11:27:55'),
(12, '47MIF-7HG96', 5, NULL, '2021-02-08 11:27:55');
```

Comment: To ensure that either all or none of the statements are executed, have a look at [transactions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#transactions).

Comment: Come up with a certain constant in the distant future, which will be used as a special mark. For example, use maximal value for the DATETIME datatype = '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. Now: (1) update table and set this value to `key_used` instead of null (2) select `prod_id` by `key_value` and this constant in `key_used` (3) update and set current timestamp instead of this constant value.